# Get the value of an element's attribute

Tags: xml, perl

I am trying to get the value of the `name` attribute of any `section` elements in some XML data.

```
my $some_att = $fileLocation->findnodes("//section[/@name]");
```

Can someone please explain what is wrong with this syntax?

Please note that the variable `$fileLocation` here opens the file location for the XML I am working with.

Comment: Are you using `XML::LibXML`?

Comment: `//section[/@name]` means "`section` elements in the null namespace which have a root element with an attribute named `name` in the null namespace." On the other hand, `//section[@name]` means "`section` elements in the null namespace which have an attribute named `name` in the null namespace."

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that you're using
[`XML::LibXML`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML)?

It's very important to explain what tools (library, language, operating system) you are using, as well as the errant behaviour you are seeing.

Your *"Please note that the variable `$fileLocation` here opens the file location for the XML I am working with"* is troubling. It doesn't make much sense (it's a variable and cannot open anything) and the identifier you have chosen implies that it is a path to the XML file. 
But to be able to call `findnodes` on it, it must be a DOM object, more specifically an instance of `XML::LibXML::Node` or a subclass.

Your code should look more like this

```
use XML::LibXML;

my $xml_file = '/path/to/file.xml';

my $dom = XML::LibXML->load_xml(
    location => $xml_file
);

my @sections = $dom->findnodes('//section');

for my $section ( @sections ) {
    next unless $section->hasAttribute('name');
    say $section->getAttribute('name');
}
```

The result of the `findnodes` method in scalar context is not a single
[`XML::LibXML::Node`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Node)
object, but instead an
[`XML::LibXML::NodeList`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::NodeList),
which is overloaded so that it bahaves similarly to a reference to an array

You don't say what errors you are getting, but from your *"Can someone please explain what is wrong with this syntax?"* I imagine that the module is rejecting your XPath expression?

In this statement

```
my $some_att = $fileLocation->findnodes("//section[/@name]")
```

the problem is with the *predicate* `[/@name]` which, if it were correct, would filter the `section` elements to include only those that have a `name` attribute. Because it is a predicate it doesn't need a *child* axis, and so should be written as `//section[@name]`

But that will only find all `section` elements that have a `name` attribute. To select the attributes themselves you need to write `//section/@name`, something like this

```
 my $section_names = $fileLocation->findnodes('//section/@name')
```

Then you will have an `XML::LibXML::NodeList` of
 [`XML::LibXML::Attr`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Attr)
objects, and you can extract the list of their values using something similar to

```
my @section_names = map { $_->value } $section_names->get_nodelist
```

You may instead prefer to start with a list of all `section` elements using the XPath expression `//section`. That would give you a collection of
 [`XML::LibXML::Element`](https://metacpan.org/pod/XML::LibXML::Element)
objects, from which you can extract the `name` element using `$elem->getAttribute('name')`

Remember that you may work with arrays instead of 
`XML::LibXML::NodeList` objects if you prefer, by choosing list context instead of scalar context in the call to `findnodes` as described in
**mob's** answer

Comment: Actually the expression is syntactically valid, but will always return an empty sequence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know Perl but I assume that findnodes() is designed to evaluate an XPath expression. Your expression

```
"//section[/@name]"
```

is syntactically correct, but semantically, it's nonsense. (As an aside, I wonder how people come up with such things? I can only imagine you're cutting and pasting from examples that you don't understand, without ever going back to the spec to see what it actually means).

Two main errors here.

- Firstly, square brackets represent a predicate or filter: you're
  selecting the sections that satisfy some condition, but your prose
  requirement (a) says you want to retrieve names (not sections), and
  (b) says nothing about filtering the list.
- Secondly, `/@name` is void. A '/' at the start of an expression selects the root (document) node, while @name selects an attribute. Document nodes don't have attributes, so this selects nothing.

The expression you want is `//section/@name`. (What you do with the names once you get them into Perl-space is outside my knowledge.)

Comment: `XML::LibXML`  is just a Perl wrapper for `libxml2`, which has [any number of language bindings and wrappers](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html). If you know the library in any language (and it's hard to get away from if you work with XML data) then the Perl ideas and classes should mirror what you already know pretty well.

Comment: Thanks Michael. Of course you're right. Developing an XSLT engine does wonders for one's knowledge of XPath syntax! The author's *"Can someone please explain what is wrong with this syntax?"* led me to assume that they were seeing a syntax error reported, and I'm not confident enough with my knowledge of XPath to reject that. (By the way, I graduated in Reading, working with Algol 68 on punched cards on an ICL 1904S!)